# Spring Boot Test does not use jmx property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx

I have a test clas with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class Foo{
    ...
}
```

which should start up a regular application context as defined by:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"de.foo", "de.bar"})
public class Application {
    ...
}
```

This works as expected. Further I have an application.yml which gets loaded in both cases but when running the test, the property for JMX (`spring.jmx.enabled`) does not get loaded or it does not get used.

I tried different property files (application.yml, application-test.yml) but the only thing what works is setting the property via

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.jmx.enabled:true")
```

The property defaults to *true* in a regular application context.

Several questions:

1. Why is the default different in a test class?
2. Why does the property not get loaded or recognized, when loading it from an application.yml (the rest of the yml works, so it does get loaded).

This seems to be a known behavior, as seen in this comment in [Spring Boot Sample Data Tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-jpa/src/test/java/sample/data/jpa/SampleDataJpaApplicationTests.java#L49). Is there any documentation I missed about this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently encountered the same situation myself, and have opened [spring-projects/spring-boot#13008](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13008) to document this behavior. As a result, the following additions to the reference manual will be added in the upcoming `1.5.13.RELEASE` and `2.0.2.RELEASE`:

> As the test context framework caches context, JMX is disabled by default to prevent identical components to register on the same domain. If such test needs access to an MBeanServer, consider marking it dirty as well:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.jmx.enabled=true")
@DirtiesContext
public class SampleJmxTests {

    @Autowired
    private MBeanServer mBeanServer;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same issue. Official docs: [43.3.5 Using JMX](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)